# How to judge if the phone is low battery when i enter app more timely

Tags: android, battery

I want to do something when enter app with low battery.I know i can register abroadcastReceiver to get the battery level,but it is not timely.How can i get the battery level more timely?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have resolved it.The receiver will receive the broadcast when we register it.The broadcast is sticky.